# Xcode 10.0 Crash every time of header import

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10

Xcode 10.0 with project in Objective-C. Each and every time Xcode crash at time of `#import ""` statement.

Comment: Please give reason for downvote.

Comment: Note that you didn't copy-paste the crash log and you didn't provide a real case scenario, as nobody ever write `#import ""`. Maybe sharing a GitHub project with a [MCVE] inside could help us understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found Solution.

[image]

Go to the path `Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings...` 
In `Pre-User Workspace setting` Change Build Setting option as **Legacy Build System**.